# Is it possible to fire the OnPropertyChanged Event without explictly calling it in the setter of a property on ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

In my scenario, every time a property is changed, I want to fire the OnPropertyChanged event

Is possible to write a base ViewModel which do it automatically, maybe passing the nameof(property) whenever a property value changes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible to fire the `PropertyChanged` event without writing code? *Yes* though you have to use a 3rd party library that injects the call in called Fody. You can find it at: https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

If you are willing to write a *little* code, you can put this in your base class (C#6 for ?. and you need `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` for `CallerMemberName`):

```
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventargs(propertyName));
}
```

so in your property setters you just put

```
set
{
   backingField = value;
   OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

Comment: What does the ? do in this case? Preventing Invoke being called when PropertyChanged is null?

Comment: @EstebanVerbel Exactly. And its thread safe. `?.Invoke` is the preferred way of raising events with C# 6. More specifically, ?. causes the expression to *return* null if the left hand argument is null; meaning that any code after it won't execute.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

[Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) allows you to use attributes to wire up INotifyPropertyChanged instead of having to explicitly call it in every setter.

```
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class Person 
{        
    public string GivenNames { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.